# ArrayList no se ejecuta desde otra clase

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo una clase que ejecuta un método de otra clase para añadir objetos a un `ArrayList`. Pero no hay forma de que me funcione. Con el depurador parece como si funcionara pero no ejecuta el `add(objeto)`. Pongo el código haber si me echáis un cable.

Clase `PeticionesAtracciones` que llama al método de `PeticionesTrabajadores` que añade el nuevo trabajador.

```
public class PeticionesAtracciones {

PeticionesTrabajadores peticionesTrabajadores = new PeticionesTrabajadores();
private String opcion;
private boolean exito;

public void nuevaAtraccion(int tipoAtraccion) {

    String nombre, idresponsable, direccion, fechaNacimiento, fechaContrato, atraccion;
    int numAyudantes;
    boolean activo;

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Nombre de la atraccion: ");
    nombre = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Nif del responsable Atraccion: ");
    idresponsable = sc.nextLine();
    if(peticionesTrabajadores.comprovarResponsable(idresponsable)){
        System.out.println("Responsable de Atraccion asignado");
        exito = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Ningun responsable con este identificativo");
        System.out.println("1.-Crear nuevo 2.-Listar Encargados atraccion 3.-Salir");
        opcion = sc.nextLine();
        if(opcion.equals("1")){       
            peticionesTrabajadores.nuevoTrabajador(2);
            idresponsable = peticionesTrabajadores.ultimoResponsable();
            exito = true; 
        }
        if(opcion.equals("2")){       
            peticionesTrabajadores.imprimirTrabajadores();
        }
        else{
            exito = false;
        }
    }
    if(exito==true){
        switch(tipoAtraccion){

            case 1 :
            TipoAC tipoAC = new TipoAC(nombre, idresponsable, 6, false, false, "Todos", 120); 
            break;

            case 2 :
            TipoAC tipoAD = new TipoAC(nombre, idresponsable, 2, false, false, "Todos", 120); 
            break;

            case 3 :
            TipoAC tipoAE = new TipoAC(nombre, idresponsable, 4, false, false, "Todos", 120); 
            break;

            case 4 :
            TipoAC tipoAF = new TipoAC(nombre, idresponsable, 7, false, false, "Todos", 120); 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Clase PeticionesTrabajadores con el método nuevoTrabajador(int)

```
public class PeticionesTrabajadores {

private ArrayList<Trabajador> trabajadores = new ArrayList();
private String opcion; //String para controlar respustas de teclado
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

/**
 * Metodo para crear un nuevo trabajador
 */
public void nuevoTrabajador(int tipoTrabajador) {

    String nombre, id, direccion, fechaNacimiento, fechaContrato, cargo, atraccion;
    boolean activo;      

    System.out.print("\f");
    System.out.println("Nombre del trabajador: ");
    nombre = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Nif del trabajador: ");
    id = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Direccion del trabajador: ");
    direccion = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Fecha Nacimiento del trabajador: ");
    fechaNacimiento = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Trabajador activo: ");
    activo = sc.nextBoolean();
    System.out.println("Fecha Contrato: ");
    fechaContrato = sc.nextLine();
    fechaContrato = sc.nextLine();
    switch(tipoTrabajador){

        case 1 :
        System.out.println("Atraccion asignada: ");
        atraccion = sc.nextLine();
        AyudanteAtraccion ayudanteAtraccion = new AyudanteAtraccion(nombre, id, direccion, fechaNacimiento, activo, fechaContrato, atraccion);
        trabajadores.add(ayudanteAtraccion);
        break;

        case 2 :
        System.out.println("Atraccion asignada: ");
        atraccion = sc.nextLine();
        ResponsableAtraccion responsableAtraccion = new ResponsableAtraccion(nombre, id, direccion, fechaNacimiento, activo, fechaContrato, atraccion);
        trabajadores.add(responsableAtraccion);
        break;

        case 3 :
        AtencionCliente atencionCliente = new AtencionCliente(nombre, id, direccion, fechaNacimiento, activo, fechaContrato);
        trabajadores.add(atencionCliente);
        break;

        case 4 :
        RelacionesPublicas relacionesPublicas = new RelacionesPublicas(nombre, id, direccion, fechaNacimiento, activo, fechaContrato);
        trabajadores.add(relacionesPublicas);
        break;
    }   
}

public void cargarTrabajadores(){

    trabajadores.add(new AyudanteAtraccion("Jon Barrow", "4111111C", "Lincon 20, 3-3", "30/05/1980", true, "1/1/2009", "Latigo"));
    trabajadores.add(new AyudanteAtraccion("Joan Sala", "42348731K", "St. Cugat 20", "03/01/1985", true, "1/1/2012", "Latigo"));
    trabajadores.add(new ResponsableAtraccion("Maria Vladimir", "5535571Q", "Pep Ventura  25", "12/01/1982", true, "1/1/2016", "Latigo"));
    trabajadores.add(new AtencionCliente("Pablo Soria", "27156841Q", "Rocacorba  25", "12/01/1982", true, "1/1/2016"));
    trabajadores.add(new RelacionesPublicas("Enrique Roca", "12587415Q", "Pirineus  25", "12/01/1982", true, "1/1/2016"));
}

public void imprimirTrabajadores(){
    System.out.print("\f");
    for(Trabajador trabajador : trabajadores) {
        if (trabajador instanceof AyudanteAtraccion) {
        AyudanteAtraccion t = (AyudanteAtraccion) trabajador;
        imprimirTrabajador(t);
        System.out.println("Atraccion: " + t.getatraccionAsignada());
        }
        if (trabajador instanceof ResponsableAtraccion) {
        ResponsableAtraccion t = (ResponsableAtraccion) trabajador;
        imprimirTrabajador(t);
        System.out.println("Atraccion: " + t.getatraccionAsignada());
        }
        if (trabajador instanceof AtencionCliente) {
        AtencionCliente t = (AtencionCliente) trabajador;
        imprimirTrabajador(t);
        }
        if (trabajador instanceof RelacionesPublicas) {
        RelacionesPublicas t = (RelacionesPublicas) trabajador;
        imprimirTrabajador(t);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Pulse una tecla para continuar... ");
    opcion = sc.nextLine();
}

public void imprimirTrabajador(Trabajador trabajador){
    System.out.println("Nombre Trabajador: " + trabajador.getnombrePersona() + " Identificacion: " + trabajador.getidPersona());
    System.out.println(" Direccion Trabajador: " + trabajador.getdireccionPersona() + " Fecha Nacimiento: " + trabajador.getfechaNacimiento());
    System.out.println("Activo Trabajador: " + trabajador.getactivoTrabajador() + " Sueldo: " + trabajador.getSueldo() + " Fecha contrato: " + trabajador.getfechaContrato());
    System.out.println("\n");       
}

public boolean comprovarResponsable(String id){
    boolean exito = false;
    for(Trabajador trabajador : trabajadores) {
        if (trabajador instanceof ResponsableAtraccion) {
           if(id.equals(trabajador.getidPersona())){
            exito=true;
            }
        }
    }
    return exito;
}

public String ultimoResponsable(){
    int ultimo = trabajadores.size() -1;
    String idResponsable = trabajadores.get(ultimo).getidPersona();
    return idResponsable;
}
```

}

Comment: El código parece correcto. ¿Podrías dar más detalles del problema que te has encontrado? Revisa como hacer un [mcve].

Comment: Buenas @SJuan76 el problema es que si executo nuevoTrabajador desde la clase PeticionesTrabajadores carga sin problemas. Tengo un método para listar el ArrayList y muestra todos los objetos que creo. Pero cuando llamo el mismo método nuevoTrabajador desde PeticionesAtracciones no añade nada :( Pense que podria ser qe me machara el ArrayList, pero no es el caso... No sé donde puede estar el error. Quieres que ponga todo el código entero? Gracias de todas formas!

Comment: Intenta subir el código entero, por que a simple vista el código esta bien. Necesito ver mas para saber.

Comment: @Youshiro he añadido todo el código... Muchas grácias!!

Comment: *«Pero cuando llamo el mismo método nuevoTrabajador desde PeticionesAtracciones no añade nada»* ¿Podrías dar más detalles para tener más elementos de análisis? -¿Da error? ... ¿qué error?, -¿Imprime algo? ... ¿qué imprime?, etc. No es fácil meterse así sin más en la lógica del tu programa. En la parte donde pareces tener problemas tú mandas un valor `2` que crea un tipo de dato específico en el método, ¿a qué nivel has depurado cada dato? Por ejemplo, ¿llega hasta el `switch` o no? Decir *no añade nada* es muy genérico, sobre todo si no conocemos la lógica de tu programa.

Comment: Perdon :( Error no da ningún error. Con el depurador el ArrayList trabajadores funciona correctamente con la clase PeticionesTrabajadores tanto con el método nuevoTrabajador() como el método cargarTrabajadores. Con la clase PeticionesAtracciones cunado llamo al Array siempre esta vacio int lenght 0 aunque haya cargado trabajadores antes. Sospecho que me crea un nuevo ArrayList trabajadores... Es posible? Aunque el de la clase PeticionesTrabajadores sigue funcionando...

Comment: Vamos a depurar, según tú el problema estaría aquí: `if(opcion.equals("1")){       
            peticionesTrabajadores.nuevoTrabajador(2);`  ¿estoy en lo cierto? Bien, entonces modifica un poco el `switch`, en el case 2, de la clase `PeticionesTrabajadores`, poniendo algo así: `case 2 :
        System.out.println("Atraccion asignada CASE 2: ");`  y dinos si ves en pantalla  `Atraccion asignada CASE 2` A eso me refiero cuando te pido que nos digas hasta qué punto has depurado. Sino hay que ponerse a adivinar en tu código. Se trata de seguir la traza de tu código para ver dónde falla.

Comment: Si que veo "Atraccion asignada CASE 2: " Definitivamente creo que existen dos ArrayList trabajadores porque si llamo desde PeticionesAtracciones al método imprimirTrabajadores() me imprime los trabajadores creados al asignar una atraccion y si ejecuto el método imprimirTrabajadores() desde PeticionesTrabajadores me imprime los trabajadores creados desde allí. Puede ser que al llamar PeticionesTrabajadores peticionesTrabajadores = new PeticionesTrabajadores(); desde PeticionesAtracciones se me cree un nuevo ArrayList? Gracias por la ayuda y siento no ser más concreto